# Alternating sine wave with square-wave in Python

Tags: python, signals

How do I create a randomly alternating sequence of a sine wave and a square wave in Python? I need 11,000 timestamps, so I generated a numeric sequence:

`t = np.linspace(0, 11000, endpoint = False)`

The randonmly alternating sequence of sine wave and square wave needs to look like this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBjL3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach in which the code continuously generates values and has a certain probability of flipping the wave between square and sine:

```py
import math
from random import random

SWITCH_PROBABILITY = 0.25

sine_wave = True

def x_value(t):
    return t

def y_value(t):
    # Determine whether to flip the wave we're producing.
    if random() < SWITCH_PROBABILITY:
        sine_wave = not sine_wave # Flip the wave.

    if sine_wave:
        # We are generating a sine wave.
        return math.sin(t)
    else:
        # We are generating a square wave.
        return math.copysign(1, math.sin(t))
```

Since I'm not sure how you're generating values or using them, I can't provide more details. You would probably want to define some time resolution and step through, generating many coordinate pairs as `(x_value(t), y_value(t))`.

Comment: Thank you! And how do I generate the plot? I tried this, but it prints a blank sheet.
t = np.linspace(0, 11000, endpoint = False) 
for item in t:
    x = x_value(item)
    y = y_value(item)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()